# Rotation (with css) in button at firefox doesn't work, unless cursor is in center. Works great on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, rotation, mozilla

In one application, called "scheduler", the user shall click on some buttons.

In `chrome` the rotation is executed as desired, but on `Firefox`, the button will rotate if the user moves the cursor at the center of the button.

The bad thing is that, the rotation starts and shall not be completed, if the user puts the cursor somewhere else in the button.

You can see it in action [**here**](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%B2%CE%B9/%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%B2%CE%AF-results/).

It seems that the behaviour is affected heavily by which version of firefox one uses.

However, this "bug" of `Firefox`, in my opinion, made me remove the feature. If anything alternative has been found after so much time, it would be highly welcomed.

Comment: in firefox 26 it rotates whenever the cursor goes inside the button, same in chrome 30 http://jsfiddle.net/sf5zM/2/

Comment: On FF 23, your fiddle will have the same behavior as the one I stated. Since the "bug" is not produced from mine code, I am going to edit my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NorthPole stated:

in `firefox` 26 it rotates whenever the cursor goes inside the button, same in `chrome 30`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sf5zM/2/)

However, many users (included me) are using a version of `firefox` that suffer from this behaviour, so I just removed the feature.

Also, some mobile users were complaining heavily about that.